# which mail program will be used in crontab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, cron

Platform: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

User: root

Desc:
  If there is any output to stdout/stderr in execution, crontab will collect them and mail to correspond owner. In my case, it is 'root'. When I look at syslog, I found an error:

`Jan 18 15:53:01 ali00 CRON[10261]: (root) CMD (some command)
Jan 18 15:53:03 ali00 sSMTP[10265]: 553 Mail from must equal authorized user
Jan 18 15:53:03 ali00 CRON[10260]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x0001, #012)`

(In my system, I use ssmtp to send mail)

Since I cannot see any detail, how to debug this error? Do I need to change something in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf? Furthermore, there is no `mail` command in my system, how does crontab know to use `ssmtp` rather than `mail`?

Comment: Oh, I found the solution. Just edit /etc/ssmtp/revaliases to set the real email address for each account.